# SQL Server 2008/2012 Express install fails on scenarioengine.exe

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express on a Windows 7 64-bit PC.  It also fails to install SQL Server 2008 R2.  The bootstrapper extracts all the files, runs setup.exe (with UAC popup) then (from what I can tell) tries to launch scenarioengine.exe which refuses to run.

The error details from MSSQL 2012 Express are:

> Description:   Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:
>   Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
>   Problem Signature 01: scenarioengine.exe
>   Problem Signature 02: 11.0.2100.60
>   Problem Signature 03: 4f35e1de
>   Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure
>   Problem Signature 05: 11.0.0.0
>   Problem Signature 06: 4f35e1dd
>   Problem Signature 07: 200
>   Problem Signature 08: 179
>   Problem Signature 09: ZAGSF01GRLFWVJMY5S0U0HXSJJE2HDT4
>   OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>   Locale ID:    1033

I extracted the install files and ran from a command line, and I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException:
>   The environment block used to start a process cannot be longer than
>   65535 bytes.  Your environment block is 162180 bytes long.  Remove
>   some environment variables and try again.  --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The environment block used to start
>   a process cannot be longer than 65535 bytes.  Your environment block
>   is 162180 bytes long.  Remove some environment variables and try
>   again.
>
> at System.Diagnostics.EnvironmentBlock.ToByteArray(StringDictionary sd,
>   Boolean unicode)
>   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine) 
>   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine) 
>   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters
>   options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String
>   arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String
>   trueArgs)
>   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames)
>   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)
>   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)
>   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly,
>   Hashtable assemblies)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings,
>   Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence
>   evidence)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping
>   xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String
>   rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String
>   rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SetCommonFlag(String
>   key, Boolean value)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.InitializeLogProviders(ServiceContainer
>   context)    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Run()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Start()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Main()

The key bit I think is here:
`The environment block used to start a process cannot be longer than 65535 bytes.  Your environment block is 162180 bytes long.  Remove some environment variables and try again.`
I get this specific error in the GUI when trying MSSQL2008 Express, so looks like it's the root cause of both failures.

The error *looks* like a 32-bit/64-bit incompatibility, but the GUI error code of CLR20r3 implies a .NET framework corruption.  Some reports on the Internet claim this could be due to an issue when [an embedded OS is cloned](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6bf008a-9afe-4e81-8f97-248c814da1f2/wince6-compilation-error-environment-block-too-long?forum=winembplatdev), but this isn't an embedded OS.  It *might* be a volume-licensed OS that has been cloned onto the PC, but it's not an embedded OS.

I've tried reinstalling .NET 3.5.1 (through Add/Remote Windows Components & Features, as it's built in to Windows 7), and have installed .NET 4.5 too just in case - both [re]install fine.

Additional PC info:
- Windows 7 Pro with SP1;
- 64-bit;
- 8GB RAM;
- Intel Core i5-3550
- Connecting to PC remotely using LogMeIn (as this is a customer's computer).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the client's environment variables.  The command "set" should echo them back to you.

Comment: Yes, I checked them.  Nothing odd there.  And they certainly don't look longer than usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this now.  For other people's info: I got the customer to run the SQL install directly on the PC (so not via a LogMeIn session), and it worked fine.  So looks like LogMeIn was causing all the problems!  I knew Remote Desktop shouldn't be used (according to Microsoft's prerequisites), but LogMeIn was not mentioned.  They must use the same underlying hooks into the system that cause incompatibility with the install.